# Modifying how categories are built in bm_categories.php

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, oscommerce

I'm hoping someone might be able to give me a hand with modifying the category link creation. I've modified it already and have been successful for the most part, but this last bit is killing me.

Contents of bm_categories.php:

```
    <?php
    /*
      $Id$

      osCommerce, Open Source E-Commerce Solutions
      http://www.oscommerce.com

      Copyright (c) 2010 osCommerce

      Released under the GNU General Public License
    */

      class bm_categories {
        var $code = 'bm_categories';
        var $group = 'boxes';
        var $title;
        var $description;
        var $sort_order;
        var $enabled = false;


        function bm_categories() {
          $this->title = MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_TITLE;
          $this->description = MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION;

          if ( defined('MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_STATUS') ) {
            $this->sort_order = MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_SORT_ORDER;
            $this->enabled = (MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_STATUS == 'True');

            $this->group = ((MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_CONTENT_PLACEMENT == 'Left Column') ? 'boxes_column_left' : 'boxes_column_right');
          }
        }

function tep_show_category($counter) {
          global $tree, $categories_string, $cPath_array;

      $categories_string .= '<a href="';

          if ($tree[$counter]['parent'] == 0) {
            $cPath_new = 'cPath=' . $counter;
          } else {
            $cPath_new = 'cPath=' . $tree[$counter]['path'];
          }

          $categories_string .= tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, $cPath_new) . '">';

      if ($tree[$counter]['parent'] == 0) {
        $categories_string .= '<h2>' . $tree[$counter]['name'] . '</h2></a>';
      } else {
        if (isset($last_id)) {
        $categories_string .= '<h3 class="subCategories">' . $tree[$counter]['name'] . '</h3></a>';
      } else {
        $categories_string .= $tree[$counter]['name'] . '</a>';
      }
      }

          if (SHOW_COUNTS == 'true') {
            $products_in_category = tep_count_products_in_category($counter);
            if ($products_in_category > 0) {
                  $categories_string .= '&nbsp;(' . $products_in_category . ')';
            }
          }


          if ($tree[$counter]['next_id'] != false) {
            $this->tep_show_category($tree[$counter]['next_id']);
          }
          }

        function getData() {
          global $categories_string, $tree, $languages_id, $cPath, $cPath_array;

          $categories_string = '';
          $tree = array();

          $categories_query = tep_db_query("select c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, c.parent_id from " . TABLE_CATEGORIES . " c, " . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . " cd where c.parent_id = '0' and c.categories_id = cd.categories_id and cd.language_id='" . (int)$languages_id ."' order by sort_order, cd.categories_name");
          while ($categories = tep_db_fetch_array($categories_query))  {
            $tree[$categories['categories_id']] = array('name' => $categories['categories_name'],
                                                        'parent' => $categories['parent_id'],
                                                        'level' => 0,
                                                        'path' => $categories['categories_id'],
                                                        'next_id' => false);

            if (isset($parent_id)) {
              $tree[$parent_id]['next_id'] = $categories['categories_id'];
            }

            $parent_id = $categories['categories_id'];

            if (!isset($first_element)) {
              $first_element = $categories['categories_id'];
            }
          }

          if (tep_not_null($cPath)) {
            $new_path = '';
            reset($cPath_array);
            while (list($key, $value) = each($cPath_array)) {
              unset($parent_id);
              unset($first_id);
              $categories_query = tep_db_query("select c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, c.parent_id from " . TABLE_CATEGORIES . " c, " . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . " cd where c.parent_id = '" . (int)$value . "' and c.categories_id = cd.categories_id and cd.language_id='" . (int)$languages_id ."' order by sort_order, cd.categories_name");
              if (tep_db_num_rows($categories_query)) {
                $new_path .= $value;
                while ($row = tep_db_fetch_array($categories_query)) {
                  $tree[$row['categories_id']] = array('name' => $row['categories_name'],
                                                       'parent' => $row['parent_id'],
                                                       'level' => $key+1,
                                                       'path' => $new_path . '_' . $row['categories_id'],
                                                       'next_id' => false);

                  if (isset($parent_id)) {
                    $tree[$parent_id]['next_id'] = $row['categories_id'];
                  }

                  $parent_id = $row['categories_id'];

                  if (!isset($first_id)) {
                    $first_id = $row['categories_id'];
                  }

                  $last_id = $row['categories_id'];
                }
                $tree[$last_id]['next_id'] = $tree[$value]['next_id'];
                $tree[$value]['next_id'] = $first_id;
                $new_path .= '_';
              } else {
                break;
              }
            }
          }

          $this->tep_show_category($first_element);

          $data = '<article class="ui-widget infoBoxContainer">' .
                  '  <h1 class="ui-widget-header infoBoxHeading">' . MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_BOX_TITLE . '</h1>' .
                  '  <nav class="ui-widget-content infoBoxContents">' . $categories_string . '</nav>' . 
                  '</article>';

          return $data;
        }

        function execute() {
          global $SID, $oscTemplate;

          if ((USE_CACHE == 'true') && empty($SID)) {
            $output = tep_cache_categories_box();
          } else {
            $output = $this->getData();
          }

          $oscTemplate->addBlock($output, $this->group);
        }

        function isEnabled() {
          return $this->enabled;
        }

        function check() {
          return defined('MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_STATUS');
        }

        function install() {
          tep_db_query("insert into " . TABLE_CONFIGURATION . " (configuration_title, configuration_key, configuration_value, configuration_description, configuration_group_id, sort_order, set_function, date_added) values ('Enable Categories Module', 'MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_STATUS', 'True', 'Do you want to add the module to your shop?', '6', '1', 'tep_cfg_select_option(array(\'True\', \'False\'), ', now())");
          tep_db_query("insert into " . TABLE_CONFIGURATION . " (configuration_title, configuration_key, configuration_value, configuration_description, configuration_group_id, sort_order, set_function, date_added) values ('Content Placement', 'MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_CONTENT_PLACEMENT', 'Left Column', 'Should the module be loaded in the left or right column?', '6', '1', 'tep_cfg_select_option(array(\'Left Column\', \'Right Column\'), ', now())");
          tep_db_query("insert into " . TABLE_CONFIGURATION . " (configuration_title, configuration_key, configuration_value, configuration_description, configuration_group_id, sort_order, date_added) values ('Sort Order', 'MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_SORT_ORDER', '0', 'Sort order of display. Lowest is displayed first.', '6', '0', now())");
        }

        function remove() {
          tep_db_query("delete from " . TABLE_CONFIGURATION . " where configuration_key in ('" . implode("', '", $this->keys()) . "')");
        }

        function keys() {
          return array('MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_STATUS', 'MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_CONTENT_PLACEMENT', 'MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_SORT_ORDER');
        }
      }
    ?>
```

I've only modified the function tep_show_category that starts on line 34.  I'm not getting any errors.  However, it's not functioning the way I would like either, and I can't seem to figure out how. ;)

What I want to happen is if a category is a parent cat, assign  tag. If it's a child cat, assign  tag.  Unless a subcategory is currently selected, then use no h tags.

The  for parent, and  for child are working great. However I'm having difficulty getting it to see if a subcat is current page or not.

I'm just not sure where I should be looking to see if subcat is selected. It seems in the link creation it uses $first_id + $last_id to build the cPath parameters. i.e the 1_4 in indxp.phhp?cPath=1_4. So, I've tried taking the approach of using isset to see if $last_id is empty...but no such luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For you check if you are on the same categorie, no matter if it is a top level parent or a sub level parent, you only must to add the global cPath to the escope of the function and compare it with the cPath_new.

the cPath comes from the application_top, so you can access it as a global.

```
if (cPath != cPath_new){ this_is_not_the_current_categorie(); } 
else { this_is_the_current_categorie(); }
```